# Adding controls to an update panel without removing what's already there

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there anyway to add controls to an update panel without removing what is already on it?
For example,

```
public void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label testLabel = new Label();
    testLabel.Text = "Test Text";
    UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(testLabel);
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
```

Will just show up with "Test Text" just once no matter how many times it's called.

I am trying to add different controls so doing a counter and just adding the same thing multiple times is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: This way you *dynamically* add a `Label` control. Hence, it has to be added again after every post-back.

Comment: ASP.NET web application or WinForms desktop application?